# Data properties in SFC considered not defined after migrating from Vue CLI to Vite

Tags: vuejs2, vite

I'm using Vue 2.7 and I have the following SFC Vue file :

```js
<template>
    <v-container fluid>
      <v-row dense class="justify-center">
        <v-col
          v-for="card in cards"
          :key="card.title"
        >
          <v-card>
            <v-card-title>{{ card.title }}</v-card-title>
          </v-card>
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
    </v-container>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  name: 'MainList',
  data: () => ({
    cards: [
      { title: 'My-title', version: "1.1"},
    ],
  })
};
</script>
```

Everything worked fine until I came up migrating from Vue CLI to Vite.
Now, I get the following error when mounting component:

```
[Vue warn]: Property or method "cards" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property
```

here is my `vite.config.js`:

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue2'
import Components from 'unplugin-vue-components/vite'
import {
  VuetifyResolver,
} from 'unplugin-vue-components/resolvers'

const path = require("path");
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    vue(),
    Components({
      resolvers: [
        VuetifyResolver(),
      ],
    })
    
  ],
  resolve: {
    alias: [
      {find: "@", replacement: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src')}
    ],
  },
  server: {
    port: 8080,
  },
});
```

I'm confused why everything in `data` is not interpreted when rendering. Am I missing something ?